# Building a highway at the minimum cost

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, applications, operations-research

I am asked the following question:

> You are responsible for building a highway that connects A to B. There's an old highway 50 miles south that can be restored at the cost of \$300.000,00 per mile. Building a new path requires \$500.000,00 per mile. Find the optimal path that minimizes the cost.

[image: problem]

So we can call the projections of A and B A' and B', and the midpoints between them X and Y.

[image]

Using a straight path from A to B would require \$75.000.000,00 and going AA'B'B would require \$95.000.000,00. Sonlet's find an optimal point on the middle.

The cost function is given by

$$
C = 2 \cdot 500000 \sqrt{50^2+x^2}  + 300000(150-2x)\\
C' = \frac{10x}{\sqrt{x^2+2500}}-6=0
$$

If we say $C'=0$ we don't find any critical points. Did I do a miscalculation? And if not, what is the conclusion of the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation $C'=0$ does have a solution. Add $6$ to both sides, multiply by $\sqrt{x^2+2500}$, then square both sides, getting
$$
100x^2 = 36(x^2+2500)
$$
which has the solution $x=300/8$.

Comment: Sure I just simplified it.

Comment: But you simplified incorrectly: the correct way to simplify would be$$C'=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{2500+x^2}}\cdot5-6=0.$$

Comment: Youre right I forgot to put the 500 factor, thank you

Comment: That said, we still get complex roots for the equationr ight?

Comment: @bru1987 There is a real (and positive) root. Whether that gives the optimal path or not remains to be verified.

Comment: So what I have (using the root $75/2$ is a cost of \$85 million, but that is more costly than just building a highway straight from A to B (which would cost \$75 million) right?

Comment: @bru1987 Correct.